# retrieve HMCharacteristic from NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have an issue while retrieving the string from the NSPredicate. I am preparing the NSPredicate from HMCharacteristicWriteAction like below

```
 HMCharacteristicWriteAction *chWr = [conditionEvents1 objectAtIndex:a];

 NSPredicate *pred =  [HMEventTrigger predicateForEvaluatingTriggerWithCharacteristic:chWr.characteristic relatedBy:NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType toValue:chWr.targetValue];
```

If I print the **pred** object it prints like characteristic == `<HMCharacteristic>` AND characteristicValue == 1. I am trying to retrieve the value from the **pred** object for getting the HMCharacteristicObject.It is giving the NSString in return.How can I get the HMCHaracteristic from NSPredicate. Thank you for reading my post.

Comment: Is it for debug purpose? If not, you can't. There is no property from NSPredicate that you can get like that, and "reverse engineering" the `description` of `NSPredicate` isn't a good way to do it.

Comment: This is not for debug purpose. My requirement is I am preparing the Predicate and I have to prepare the HMCharacteristicWriteAction object. So I have only one option that have to get the data from NSPredicate